# Disable Serialization for Specific Property in XML

Tags: c#, xml

I have service which is doing a lot of things and then returns xml. my task was to add `DateDeleted` property to it but that field must not be in xml.

```
[DataMember(IsRequired = true, EmitDefaultValue = true, Order = 15)]
[Column(TypeName = "datetime")]
public DateTime? DateDeleted { get; set; }
```

I add `[XmlIgnore]` attribute to it but

```
         <Organization>
            <ID>4</ID>
            <ParentID>0</ParentID>
            <Name>name</Name>
            ...
            <DateDeleted i:nil="true"/>
        </Organization>
```

It anyway apperas here. XmlIgnore did job that in xml it dont gets value. How can I remove that tag from returned xml?

Comment: Remove the `[DataMember]` annotation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `DataMember` and you don't need `[XmlIgnore]` too.

Answer (score 0):

You can disable serialization using the below:

```
    [XmlIgnore]
    public DateTime? DateDeleted { get; set; }
```